# How to update a ScrollView after adding an item in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

how can I refresh my ScrollView after adding an RadioButton. Practically I have an Item class(Task) with Layout where I defined my object, an adapter class for the ScrollView, MainActivity with it's Layout and another Activity with it's Layout. In the main Layout I start with 3 "Tasks" and by a floating button I am navigating to the second Activity with a Plain Text and a Button. If I enter a text and press the button it won't add my item to the MainActivity's ScrollView UNTIL I check a Radio Button. What I want to do is when I get back to my MainActivity's Layout to see without checking any Radio Buttons the new Task.

I have notifyingData in my adapter class that works perfect updating the FIXED Tasks added from Strings. I also tried to use notifyingData by other classes to update the ScrollView but nothing changes.

---

Main Activity

```
package com.example.dotomorrow;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String KEY_ID_COUNTER = "ID_COUNTER";

    private int id_number = 0;
    private RecyclerView recyclerview_Task;
    private RecyclerViewTaskAdapter adapter;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingbutton_TaskAdd;

    public static ArrayList<Task> Tasks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Initialing();




        id_number++;
        Tasks.add(new Task(id_number, "Do your homework", false));
        adapter.setTasks(Tasks);

        id_number++;
        Tasks.add(new Task(id_number, "Breakfast", false));
        adapter.setTasks(Tasks);

        id_number++;
        Tasks.add(new Task(id_number, "Hello", false));
        adapter.setTasks(Tasks);


        floatingbutton_TaskAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id_number++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskAddActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_ID_COUNTER,id_number);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });







    }
    private void Initialing() {
        adapter = new RecyclerViewTaskAdapter(this);
        recyclerview_Task = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_Task);
        floatingbutton_TaskAdd = findViewById(R.id.floatingbutton_TaskAdd);

        recyclerview_Task.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerview_Task.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));

        Tasks = new ArrayList<>();

    }


//    public void TaskAdd(int id, String text, boolean isDone) {
//        Tasks.add(new Task(id, text, isDone));
//        adapter.setTasks(Tasks);
//    }



}
```

Main Activity (Layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Platform.MaterialComponents.Light"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_main">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_Task">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/constraintlayout_Task">


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_Task"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout_FloatingButton"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">


        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingbutton_TaskAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:rippleColor="#FFF"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#FF9800"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_floatingbutton_add"
            app:maxImageSize="35dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Task

```
package com.example.dotomorrow;

import android.opengl.Visibility;

public class Task {

    private int id;
    private String text;
    private boolean isdone;

    public Task(int id, String text, boolean isdone) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
        this.isdone = isdone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Task{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", isdone=" + isdone +
                '}';
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public boolean isIsdone() {
        return isdone;
    }

    public void setIsdone(boolean isdone) {
        this.isdone = isdone;
    }


    
}
```

Item Layout (not related/connected with Task class)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp">

</com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton>
```

RecyclerViewTaskAdapter

```
package com.example.dotomorrow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewTaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewTaskAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewTaskAdapter";

    ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewTaskAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()) . inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Called");
        holder.parent.setText(tasks.get(position).getText());

        holder.parent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (removeTask(tasks.get(position))) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.parent.setChecked(false);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

}

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return tasks.size();
    }



    public void setTasks(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public RadioButton parent;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);

    }
}


    private boolean removeTask(Task task) {
        return tasks.remove(task);
    }
}
```

TaskAddActivity

```
package com.example.dotomorrow;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TaskAddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int id_number;
    private RecyclerViewTaskAdapter adapter;
    private Button button_TaskAdd;
    private EditText edittext_Task;
    private Spinner spinner_TaskWhenToDo;
    private ArrayList<Task> Tasks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_add);
        Initialing();


        System.out.println(id_number);


        button_TaskAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //ToDo Bug adaugare task

                Tasks.add(new Task(id_number, edittext_Task.getText().toString(), false));
                adapter.setTasks(Tasks);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                onBackPressed();
                Toast.makeText(TaskAddActivity.this, "Task added succsessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }


    private void Initialing() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        id_number = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.KEY_ID_COUNTER,0);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewTaskAdapter(this);
        button_TaskAdd = findViewById(R.id.button_TaskAdd);
        edittext_Task = findViewById(R.id.edittext_Task);
        spinner_TaskWhenToDo = findViewById(R.id.spinner_TaskWhenToDo);
        Tasks = MainActivity.Tasks;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
//        Intent intent = new Intent(TaskAddActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
//        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

TaskAddLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TaskAddActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_TaskAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_Task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Task"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_TaskWhenToDo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:entries="@array/task_when_to_do"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edittext_Task"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edittext_Task"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edittext_Task" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: The problem was that onBindViewHolder wasn't getting called after the item was added (every adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() was used before the item would be added. So someone got me with the idea of an infinity thread which notifies once in a while and the onBindViewHolder finally gets called.

```
package com.example.dotomorrow;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.sql.Ref;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String KEY_ID_COUNTER = "ID_COUNTER";

    private int id_number = 0;
    private RecyclerView recyclerview_Task;
    private RecyclerViewTaskAdapter adapter;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingbutton_TaskAdd;

    public static ArrayList<Task> Tasks;


    private ScrollView scrollview_Task;
//    RelativeLayout relativelayout_main;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Initialing();
        Refresh_Timer();




        id_number++;
        Tasks.add(new Task(id_number, "Do your homework", false));
        adapter.setTasks(Tasks);

        id_number++;
        Tasks.add(new Task(id_number, "Breakfast", false));
        adapter.setTasks(Tasks);

        id_number++;
        Tasks.add(new Task(id_number, "Hello", false));
        adapter.setTasks(Tasks);




//        scrollview_Task.requestLayout();
//        scrollview_Task.postInvalidate();





        floatingbutton_TaskAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id_number++;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TaskAddActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(KEY_ID_COUNTER,id_number);
                startActivity(intent);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "At First Point", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                scrollview_Task.invalidate();
//                scrollview_Task.requestLayout();



            }
        });


        Toast.makeText(this, "At Second Point", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("At Second Point");
//        scrollview_Task.invalidate();
//        scrollview_Task.requestLayout();




    }
    private void Initialing() {
        adapter = new RecyclerViewTaskAdapter(this);
        recyclerview_Task = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_Task);
        floatingbutton_TaskAdd = findViewById(R.id.floatingbutton_TaskAdd);

        recyclerview_Task.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerview_Task.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 1));

        Tasks = new ArrayList<>();



//        relativelayout_main = findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_main);
        scrollview_Task = findViewById(R.id.scrollview_Task);

    }


//    public void TaskAdd(int id, String text, boolean isDone) {
//        Tasks.add(new Task(id, text, isDone));
//        adapter.setTasks(Tasks);
//    }



    private void Refresh_Timer() {
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Refresh();
                        System.out.println("YEP");
                    }
                });
            }
        },0,5000);
    }


    private void Refresh() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try call on your ScrollView:
`scrollview_Task.invalidate()` and (or) `scrollview_Task.requestLayout()`

Comment: Nope, it hasn't solved the problem, I still have to check (delete) one Task to show the added one. It's interesting if I add multiple tasks and I check (delete) only one it will add all the added tasks.  I believe is something in the adapter that he likes to show the whole items.